# projectile-run-project without prompt

Tags: projectile

When I execute the function projectile-run-project I'm prompted to enter a run command. Fortunately the run command is already pre-set, because I added projectile-project-run-cmd to .dir-locals.el.

Ideally I would like projectile to immediately run the provided command without prompting me further. From reading the documentation I thought this is possible by providing an argument, so I tried this:

```
;; insdide use-package
:bind (([f5] .(lambda () (interactive) (projectile-run-project 'projectile-run-project-cmd))))
```

But when I press F5 now, I just get presented with the same pre-filled prompt again.

Is it possible to just immediately run the project executable?

Bonus question: Can you configure projectile-run-project-cmd inside the .projectile file or something, instead of using .dir-locals.el?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation of `projectile-run-project` command describes this.

> (projectile-run-project ARG)
>
> Run project run command.
>
> Normally you’ll be prompted for a compilation command, unless variable
>   ‘**compilation-read-command**’.  You can force the prompt with a prefix
>   ARG.

So what you can do is:

```el
(defun my-projectile-run-project (&optional prompt)
  (interactive "P")
  (let ((compilation-read-command
         (or (not (projectile-run-command (projectile-compilation-dir)))
             prompt)))
    (projectile-run-project prompt)))
```

This command will always run the previous shell command, unless it's used for the first time or it was called with a prefix argument.

Comment: I was not able to understand the documentation, but your function does what I want. Actually, I don't understand what the function does, either. For example I get the same result if I omit the (or (not)) part and simply (let (compilation-read-command prompt) ...).

Comment: The first argument to `or` is there to check if this command was run previously.